# Two pages and one navigation

Tags: php, html, css

I am working with two pages which have included the navigation menu. The problem I am having is to show which one is active. Right now Rapport stays active all the time, even if I am in the diagram. I noticed that $page is always returning Rapport, which I dont know why.

In the diagram (index.php) I have:

```
include('../rapport/navigasjon.html'); 
 $page = 'diagram';
 $_SESSION['diagram']= $page;
```

In the rapport (index.php) I have:

```
include('navigasjon.html');
$page = 'rapport';
$_SESSION['rapport']= $page;
```

And in navigasjon.html I have:

```
session_start();
$page = $_SESSION['diagram'];
 $page =  $_SESSION['rapport'];
```

AND:

```
   <li  class='pil <?php if($page=='rapport') {echo 'active';} ?>'> <a href="../rapport/index.php" class='rapport' >Rapport</a></li> 
   <li  class='pil <?php if($page=='diagram') {echo 'active';} ?>' ><a href="../diagram/index.php" class='diagram' >Diagram</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `$page` variable BEFORE including your navigation :

diagram/index.php :

```
$page = 'diagram';
$_SESSION['diagram']= $page;
include('../rapport/navigasjon.html');
```

and rapport/index.php :

```
$page = 'rapport';
$_SESSION['rapport']= $page;
include('navigasjon.html');
```

In navigasjon.html remove these lines :

```
$page = $_SESSION['diagram'];
$page =  $_SESSION['rapport'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. :/ Still rapport stays active even fi I am in diagram.

Comment: also name it navigasjon.php maybe (see the source of the html page, I bet php is interpreted as html).

Comment: No progress! I am very unsure why it only return rapport even if I am in diagram.

Comment: Edited, you'll need to remove some lines (and you may as well remove all what's related to sessions, you don't need to use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set a class to an active menu, you can try to this using directories names.

```
&lt;?php
$pathInfo = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$page = strtolower(end(explode('/', $pathinfo['dirname'])));
?>

&lt;li  class='pil &lt;?php if($page=='rapport') {echo 'active';} ?>'> &lt;a     href="../rapport/index.php" class='rapport' >Rapport&lt;/a>&lt;/li> 
&lt;li  class='pil &lt;?php if($page=='diagram') {echo 'active';} ?>' >&lt;a href="../diagram/index.php" class='diagram' >Diagram&lt;/a>&lt;/li>
```